# What is the work flow for Relay and React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I recently start using React.js I start using the flux pattern which make it easy for me to create project structure and development workflow I mean am confidant to start by

1. creating an action
2. dispatch it to dispatcher
3. call a store
4. update view

However, when start using Relay am not sure about the development flow any more, I can start by creating component then GraphQL schema or the reverse. I did not find any digram explain the flow so my question is what the Relay development workflow !